# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 C# USB DeviceWatcher

Tags: c#, usb, raspberry-pi3, enumerate, windows-iot-core-10

I manage to enumerate my USB device as below. How can I add the enumerateDevices into DeviceWatcher? 
I have referred to the following examples but still not getting any progress.
The watcher did trigger once during the startup subsequently any changes in my usb devices doesn't show anything.

[How to get notifications if devices are added, removed, or changed (XAML)][1]
 [Device Enumeration Samples][2] Any idea how to constantly monitoring the changes on my USB port to prompt if any of the USB device has been removed or connected?

```
private void StartWatcher()
    {
        usbStorageWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);
        audioCaptureWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);
        audioRenderWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.AudioRender);

        usbStorageWatcherAdded = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformation>(async (watcher, deviceInfo) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
            {
                var usbDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);
                if (usbDevices.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < usbDevices.Count; i++)
                    {
                        usbDeviceList.Add(usbDevices[i]);
                    }
                    usbList.SelectedItem = usbDevices[0];
                    usbDeviceCount.Text = usbDevices.Count.ToString();
                    GeneralMessage.Text = String.Format("{0} USB Storage found.", usbDevices.Count);
                }


            });
        });
        usbStorageWatcher.Added += usbStorageWatcherAdded;

usbStorageWatcherRemoved = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>(async (watcher, deviceInfoUpdate) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
            {
                var usbDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);
                if (usbDevices.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < usbDevices.Count; i++)
                    {
                        usbDeviceList.Add(usbDevices[i]);
                    }
                    usbList.SelectedItem = usbDevices[0];
                    usbDeviceCount.Text = usbDevices.Count.ToString();
                    GeneralMessage.Text = String.Format("{0} USB Storage found.", usbDevices.Count);
                }

            });
        });
        usbStorageWatcher.Removed += usbStorageWatcherRemoved;
```

Comment: After added `usbStorageWatcher.Start();` your code works for me with PortableStorageDevice. I can receive added and removed events.

Comment: Where should I add the us storagewatcher.start()? But I didn't get it to work continuously..

Comment: You can put it at the end of the `StartWatcher()` method.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out.